# useEffect() makes my application hang when I click on select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have 2 JSON files.

destination.json:

```
[
   {
     "id": "1",
     "destination": "usa"
   },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "destination": "canada"
      }
]
```

places.json

```
[
      {
        "country": "canada",
        "places": "toronto"
      },
      {
        "country": "usa",
        "places": "new york"
          }
    ]

const App = (props) =>{
   const [data, setData] = useState([])
   const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([])

   let item;
   const filter(options){
   //do something
   }
   useEffect(()=>{
      if(data){
         item = [destination, places].reduce((p,q =>
                p.map((c,i) => Object.assign({},{country:[c.destination], 
                places: q[i].places})))

  setData(item)
  }
},[data])

return(
   <div>
      <div>
         <Select onChange={(e)=> filter(e)}>
            <Option value="usa"> USA </Option>
            <Option value="canada"> Canada </Option>
         </Select>
      </div>
      <div>
          {data.map(d=>
              <li>{d.country} : {d.places}</li>
          )}
      </div>
   </div>
)}
```

This works fine. I have the data rendered the moment I am inside the webpage. But the problem is, I have a dropdown select option. The moment I clicked on the dropdown bar, my webpage hanged. I am not sure why it's (I think) always rendering after I clicked on my select bar.

Note: my dropdown select has no logic to it yet.

Comment: `if (data)` will always resolve to `true`, because `data` will always be an array, so this is redundant. Did you instead want `if (data.length)`? Also your call to `reduce` doesn't look valid with the parentheses positioned where they are. I would think this would be causing an error.

Comment: @fubar you're right about the `if (data)`. but could you explain a little further on why the `reduce` might be the one causing the error?

Comment: This has a syntax error 

`const filter(options){
   //do something
   }`

Try:
`const filter = (options) => {
   //do something
   }`

Comment: The `reduce` function has the signature `.reduce((accumulator, element, index) => { ... }, initialValue)`. Your code doesn't match that signature.

Comment: @fubar I have removed the `reduce` function, it's still the same. seems like my application is constantly re-rendering itself.

Comment: I think the `useEffect` hook is being called again over and over, because you're having it watch for changes to `data`, which you're then changing the value of inside the hook. So every time it's finished it'll re-run.

Comment: @fubar but isn't `setData` sets the state for the next time it is being re-rendered? so if there is no new values, how did it keep re-rendering?